# Assembly: JA and JB work incorrectly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, fpu

Since my main OS is linux and have project on visual studio, I decided to use online compilers to achieve it. I found [this](http://rextester.com/) which was suggested by many. So here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
float a = 1;
float b = 20.2;
float res = 0;
float res1 = 0;

_asm { 

    FLD a
    FCOM b
    JA midi
    JMP modi           

    midi:
    FST res
    JMP OUT

    modi:
    FST res1
    JMP OUT


}
    OUT:
cout << "res = " << res << endl;
cout << "res1 = " << res1 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

My goal is simple, if `a` is greater that `b` than put `a` in `res`, otherwise in `res1`. But it seems like whatever I have in variable `a` it always jumps on `midi` and result is always `res = whatever is in a`. Hope you can help. Sorry if my questions is silly, I've just started to learn assembly. thanks :)

**P.S**
same thing goes with `JB` but the opposite. It always prints `res1 = whatever is in b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this page](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-fcom.html):

> FCOM compares ST0 with the given operand, and sets the **FPU** flags
>   accordingly.

But your `JA midi` is testing the **CPU** flags.

It goes on:

> FCOMI and FCOMIP work like the corresponding forms of FCOM and FCOMP,
>   but write their results directly to the **CPU** flags register rather
>   than the **FPU** status word, so they can be immediately followed by
>   conditional jump or conditional move instructions.

Comment: I get an error saying `source_file.cpp(13): error C2414: illegal number of operands`

Comment: @Rasty it seems that `FCOMI` cannot take a memory operand - load it into a register. But you have the basic reason why your code does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer when I posted mine :( I'm keeping it since I already wrote it

Comment: @MargaretBloom of course - yours is better researched.

Comment: Note that `FCOMI`, `FCOMIP`, `FUCOMI`, and `FUCOMIP` require a Pentium Pro or later processor. This may be important for all of the people learning assembly in 16-bit emulators!

Answer (score 4):

This is a common pitfall, [`FCOM`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_87.html) doesn't set the flags in the flags register, it sets the condition code flags in the FPU status word.
From [Intel manual 2](http://www.intel.it/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf):

> Compares the contents of register `ST(0)` and source value and sets condition code flags *C0*, *C2*, and *C3* in the FPU
>   status word according to the results (see the table below)

[image: Condition codes set by FCOM]

Where you can see that *C3* takes the role of *ZF* and *C1* of *CF*.

Use [`FCOMI`/`FUCOMI`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_88.html) (and variants) to set the flags accordingly.

> Performs an unordered comparison of the contents of registers ST(0) and ST(i) and sets the status flags ZF, PF, and
>   CF in the EFLAGS register according to the results [Table is identical to the above, where *C2* is *PF*].

The difference between `FCOMI` and `FUCOMI` is that the latter allow for unordered operands, i.e. qNaNs.

---

Alternatively you can still use `FCOM` but then move the condition codes to the flags with:

```
fnstsw ax        ;FP Not-checked STore Status Word in AX
sahf             ;Store AH into flags
```

Intel designed [`fnstsw`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_120.html) to be compatible with [`sahf`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_284.html).
The former moves *C3*, *C2* and *C1* to bit6, bit2 and bit0, respectively, of `AH`.
The latter set the flags as `RFLAGS(SF:ZF:0:AF:0:PF:1:CF) ← AH`.

---

You can also [`test`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_315.html) `ax` directly after the `fnstsw ax` as suggested in Section *8.3.6.1 Branching on the x87 FPU Condition Codes* of [manual 1](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.html).

[image: Constants to test AX against after fnstsw for various conditions]